# Google Search - Make google index profile page instantly when created

Tags: google-search

I have a website. When you sign up, it creates a profile page for you. I want Google to index that page, through script, so I don't have to do it manually. A bit like StackOverflow. Is there any way of doing that. Also: I know sitemaps can do something like that, but I wasn't sure if it did just this. If it can, please tell me. If not, please come with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think right about sitemap. It's the thing what you need to do. Create the XML sitemap just with all these profile links. Google will index these pages just from your XML sitemap file. Of course, submit that specific XML sitemap on Google with Google Search Console.

A recommendation is not to index all these profile pages. You will lose your "crawl credit". I would recommend doing some kind of filter before sent these page to index. For example, popular sites are using something like user popularity ratings or something. And they make only the most valuable profiles indexable for search engines. Please think twice do you really need to index all your profile where some of them will create it and forgot about it?

Comment: Do you know how? Like, can I execute a function when the users profile page is created that writes a url into the xml file? And do you have a generator or something to recommend? @gintsg

Comment: I usually work with more popular CMS which has ready to go plugins or solutions. @UnityLover123 can please tell what is your CMS and/or framework?

Comment: I use byet.host to host my website. Is that what you meant @gintsg ?